# Fragment with a ListView within doesn't show anything using Arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm trying to fill a Fragment that contains a ListView using an ArrayAdapter, but the ListView is completely blank once I run the app. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.medeasynetwork.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myInfoLV"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And also here is my PlaceholderFragment class inside my MainActivity class:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */

    private static int selection;
    private static int fragmentId;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        selection = sectionNumber;
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;
        ListView myInfoLV;

        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,                                                                             false);
            myInfoLV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myInfoLV);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.myInfoArray);
            myInfoLV.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;

        case 2:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_directory, container, false);
            break;

        }

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Case 2 works fine since I filled the ListView inside the XML, but when I try to use the ArrayAdapter, the ListView is shown blank. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure the array is not empty?

Comment: Pretty sure, I populated the ListView using that same array but via XML. The workaround I used was to declare the list within MainActivity, still don't know why it doesn't work the other way.